# Array.every() check if values are false

Tags: javascript

I have an array like this :

```
   myArray = {firstValue: false, secondValue: false, thirdValue: true, forthValue: false};
```

I want to check whether every value is false, if so, do something.
Example :

```
  myArray.every(x => x==false)
  //do something
```

Is that the correct way to do it ? or a function needs to be passed?

Comment: You _are_ passing a function... You may want to use `===` though.

Comment: Your array is actually an `Object` not  an `Array`. You cannot use `.every()` on objects.

Answer (score 4):

**First**. It is not an *array*, it is an *object*.

If you want to check if all values are `false`, you can get the keys via [**Object#keys**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys) and then use [**Array#every**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/every) on that array.

```js
const obj = {firstValue: false, secondValue: false, thirdValue: true, forthValue: false};

const allFalse = Object.keys(obj).every(key => obj[key] === false);

console.log(allFalse);
```

If you use ES8, you can also work with [**Object#values**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/values)

```js
const obj = {firstValue: false, secondValue: false, thirdValue: true, forthValue: false};

const allFalse = Object.values(obj).every(value => value === false);

console.log(allFalse);
```

Comment: Wouldn't it be better to use `Object.values`?

Comment: I think you mean "if all **values** are `false`"

Comment: @Andy will add also that variant

Answer (score 2):

you don't have an array, you have an object

Can use Object.values() to create the array of values to iterate

```
Object.values(myArray).every(x => x===false)
```

Note will need polyfill if using in legacy browsers

Answer (score 0):

I would do:

```
 !Object.values(myArray /*?*/).reduce((a,b) => a || b);
```

Comment: Unfortunately you lose the short-circuiting benefit found with `.every` or `.some`.

Comment: Hmm... I'm skeptical. The results flip back and forth as I re-run the test in Firefox. Logically, the short-circuiting versions should be faster, but that's never a guarantee. Anyway, on short sets, it certainly won't make a noticeable difference. On large once, I'd definitely want to halt early.

Comment: Whether or not this is faster, `.every()` seems *clearer*, IMHO. It seems like there are lots of programmers who think `.reduce()` is the right answer any time you can find a way to use it.

Comment: I've been programming a long time, and have a decent grasp of functional programming, but I still have to think hard to understand some of the ways people try to shoe-horn `.reduce()` into their solutions.

Comment: @barmar so true. But i think this is one of the rare usecases

Comment: I will admit that this isn't as inscrutible as the ones that really bother me.

Answer (score 0):

Beside the use of [`Array#every`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/every), you could use [`Array#some`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some) and take the [logical NOT `!`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Logical_Operators#Logical_NOT) value of it by using [`Boolean`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Boolean/) as a callback.

```
if (!Object.values(myObject).some(Boolean)) {
    //...
}
```

Comment: This is a good way too, though using the built-in `Boolean` became less appealing ever since arrow functions, since `.some(b=>b)` is shorter, and has the same outcome.